# Наследования шаблонов в Django

Tags: python, django

Сейчас каждый раз для меню пишу один код в каждом контроллере, это меню, которое управляется с админки. т.е.:
есть блок меню
    {% block menu %}{% endblock %}

в файле base.html

наследую
    {% extends "base.html" %}

```
{% block menu %} {%for... и т.д...%} {% endblock %}
```

и в каждом контроллере нужно вытаскивать это меню, а можно его как-то в base.html засунуть, что бы оно там всегда было?

Comment: из вашего сообщения трудно понять что вам надо, но возможно тэг https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#include вам поможет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

base.html

```
{% block menu %}
    {% include 'my_menu.html' %}
{% endblock menu %}
```

все котроллеры где НЕ нужно меню:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block menu %}{% endblock menu %} {# или что-то другое вместо меню #}
```

Comment: так это если меню статическое, у меня завязано в админке...